# How can I sort a JPA query result where the parameter is a String and the result is a List of Objects?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm writing a Spring Boot API endpoint and I need to return a list of Airlines ordered by a String (description) of 3 or more chars, the List must be sorted with the results that match the String at the beginning of the word at the top and the rest by alphabetical order

### Airline class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "airline")
public class Airline implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5962418077659300886L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String code;

    @Column
    private String description;
}
```

I get the list that matches the String but I cannot get the order right

### AirlineRepository

```
public interface AirlineRepository extends JpaRepository<Airline, Integer> {
    Airline getById(Integer id);

    List<Airline> findByDescriptionContainingIgnoreCase(String description, Pageable pageable);
    List<Airline> findByDescriptionStartsWithIgnoreCase(String description, Pageable pageable);
}
```

If I search the keyword 'ala' all airlines whose name starts with 'ala' should come first.

This is what I get

`````
{
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "message": "Execution Successful",
  "totalCount": 10,
  "content": [
    {
      "id": 962,
      "code": "6T",
      "description": "Air Mandalay"
    },
    {
      "id": 46,
      "code": "NZ",
      "description": "Air New Zealand"
    },
    {
      "id": 18,
      "code": "AS",
      "description": "Alaska Airlines"
    },
    {
      "id": 519,
      "code": "KO",
      "description": "Alaska Central Express"
    },
    {
      "id": 477,
      "code": "J5",
      "description": "Alaska Seaplane"
    },
    {
      "id": 30,
      "code": "YZ",
      "description": "ALAS URUGUAY"
    },
    {
      "id": 324,
      "code": "C9",
      "description": "Alphaland Aviation"
    },
    {
      "id": 286,
      "code": "A7",
      "description": "Calafia Airlines"
    },
    {
      "id": 330,
      "code": "CE",
      "description": "Chalair"
    },
    {
      "id": 521,
      "code": "L3",
      "description": "DHL de Guatemala"
    }
  ],
  "timestamp": null
}````
`````

Comment: Write a Comparator for Airline. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like :

```
@Query("select * from Airline a order by substring(a.description, 0,search_text_length)")
List<Airline> findAirline();
```

You can get an idea [here](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/string#substring___getting_a_portion_of_a_string)

Comment: I needed to change some syntax but it returns an empty result.
````@Query("select a from Airline a where a.description like :description order by substring(:description, 0, 3)")
    List<Airline> findAirline(@Param("description") String description, Pageable pageable);````

Answer (score 0):

Passed `description` as a sorting column and create `pageRequest` as follows. And description parameter and pageRequest send to `findByDescriptionStartsWith` method in `AirlineRepository`

```
PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest
                .of((int) Math.ceil((float) (start / pageDataSize)), pageDataSize, Sort.by('description').ascending());


List<Airline> findByDescriptionStartsWith(String description, Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not quite sure if i understood your requirement completly.

To fetch all airlines in an ordered way i would add the following method to the AirlineRepository

```
List<Airline> findByDescriptionStartsWithIgnoreCaseOrderByDescriptionAsc(String description, Pageable pageable);
```

If you also need all other airlines i would add this method, too.

```
List<Airline> findByDescriptionNotLikeIgnoreCaseOrderByDescriptionAsc(String description, Pageable pageable);
```

Add an '%' to the description and combine both lists.

Comment: I need a "starts with" and "contains", in the case that those are two separate lists I need to add one to the other and clean duplicates assuming the "startsWith" is the first list and the "contains" is the second